# Changing attribute values based on consecutive features

Tags: arcpy, pipe-network

I'm trying to determine the limiting capacity of a pipe based on the capacities of the pipes downstream of it. Basically, if Pipe A is downstream (ahead of) Pipe B and Pipe B has a capacity that is lower than Pipe A's, then Pipe A's limiting capacity would be = Pipe B's capacity. Each pipe has an upstream and downstream manhole number (INLETNODE and OUTLETNODE in the code I've attached) that I'm attempting to use as a way to move through the pipes consecutively. To start off, each pipes Pipe Capacity field and Limiting Capacity field are the same.

Here's the code I've come up with so far, as of right now the limiting capacity field doesn't get edited at all:

```
ds_pipe_dict = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(s_pipes, ["INLETNODE", "OUTLETNODE", "PIPE_CAPACITY", "LIMITING_CAPACITY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] not in ds_pipe_dict:
            ds_pipe_dict[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2],row[3]]

fields = ["INLETNODE", "OUTLETNODE", "PIPE_CAPACITY", "LIMITING_CAPACITY"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(s_pipes, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        pipe_cap = row[2]
        lim_cap = row[3]
        if row[2] == row[3]:
            ds_mh = row[1]
            pipe_cap = row[2]
            lim_cap = row[3]
            next_lim = lim_cap

            if ds_mh in ds_pipe_dict:
                if lim_cap > next_lim:
                    lim_cap = ds_pipe_dict[ds_mh][2]
                    ds_mh = ds_pipe_dict[ds_mh][0]
                else:
                    ds_mh = ds_pipe_dict[ds_mh][0]

        row[3] = lim_cap
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: What happened when 2 small pipes join and continue as a big one?

Comment: @FelixIP They don't join together, they are connected at each other's up and downstream nodes but they are their own distinct features

Comment: I know how they work. What is a highest manhole degree? How do you handle situation with more than 1 pipe sharing outlet?

Comment: @FelixIP I'm not sure what you mean by highest manhole degree. With ther two pipes into one situation, when two pipes go into one, the two upstream pipes will ideally be looking at the one upstream pipes capacity. So for example, if Pipes A and B turn into Pipe C and they both have larger capacities than Pipe C, they both receive Pipe C's capacity as their limiting capacity. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: It is clear now. Such task is not solvable in one go. Think of 100 pipes, with one last one downstream having smallest capacity. You can use either repeated summary statistics per node or repeat joins to itself using from and to nodes.

Comment: Does it really have a hydraulic meaning your Limiting Capacaty? This might have an interest in free flow pipes, but not at all in pressirized pipe. Anyway, back to free flow pipes, the capacity of a pipe is a convention based on an energy gradient according to inlet and outlet levels, but not a physical property really. The capacity assessment of a dynimic system like a real network will gain very few based on this Limiting Capacity

Answer (score 2):

You might repeat multiple joins to itself using relevant INLET and OUTLET nodes, but using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/index.html) module makes it much easier:

```
import networkx as nx
fields ="FROMN","TON","CAPACITY"
pipes="PIPES"
# create reverse graph
G=nx.DiGraph()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pipes,fields) as cursor:
    for f,t,c in cursor:
        G.add_edge(t,f,capacity=c)
# replace everything upstream with minimum
for f,t in G.edges():
    current=G[f][t]['capacity']
    upstream=nx.bfs_edges(G,t)
    for F,T in upstream:
        above=G[F][T]['capacity']
        G[F][T]['capacity']=min(current,above)
# transfer results
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pipes,fields) as cursor:
    for f,t,c in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow((f,t,G[t][f]['capacity']))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @FelixIP! I need my organization to install networkx on my computer, and when they do I'll try this out, it looks pretty promising though.

Comment: Yes, it is brilliant piece of software. Countless applications.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense:

```py
            next_lim = lim_cap

            if ds_mh in ds_pipe_dict:
                if lim_cap > next_lim:
```

Ie, `lim_cap > next_lim` will **ALWAYS** evaluate to `False` because at this point they are always going to be equal.

Additionally, you should not rely on the records in the database being retrieved in the order you want them.  Ie, your `UpdateCursor()` is not guaranteed to traverse the records in any particular order.  It will most likely retrieve them in the order in which they were initially stored, but you should not depend on this.  You need to explicitly sort them into the order you require.

You could do this by using a search cursor to read the required fields of all records into a list (eg, a list of dictionaries) and then sort that list as required.

Then when running your update cursor, your calculations could be based on looking up the record with the same OID in that sorted list of records, as well as the previous and/or next records from the sorted list as required.